# Got 23 warnings overnigth regarding NSUInteger

Tags: xcode, ios7, compiler-warnings, nsuinteger

I'm updating an old project of mine. I'm doing good progress and everything goes smooth.

Yesterday when I finished working everything was ok with my project, no errors, no warnings.

Suddenly, when today I started the project and without pressing a single key, I got 23 warnings at once. All of them are:

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'
```

Has somebody experienced something similar? why the hell was yesterday all OK and today I have sucha mess?

**Edit**. Here is some example:

```
- (IBAction)previousText:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {


    int i=[self.indexPathArray indexOfObject:[self indexPathForActiveText]];

    if (i>0) {

        [self moveRows:i-1];


    }

}
```

**Edit** It turns out that (I don't know why) the simulator I was using was iPhone retina (64 bit). I changed back to iPhone 3.5 inches (32 bit) and all the warnings went away.

Now the thing is, how do I make it compatible for both devices?

Comment: Show that line of code where it shows warning.

Comment: I think your using the Xcode 5.1 just add (int) where ever your getting the warning.

Comment: What type does your indexPathForActiveText returns ?

Comment: indexPathArray holds indexPaths. The method [self indexPathForActiveText] returns the indexpath for the active textField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use primitive C-types like `int/unsigned` and instead use the Objective-C types like `NSInteger/NSUInteger`.

These warnings will then disappear as the type sizes change depending on architecture.

Things get more interesting when you use printf-like functions as you will need to conditionally compile the formatting string, depending on architecture; for example:

```
NSInteger i = 1;
#if __LP64__
NSLog(@"i is %ld", i);
#else
NSLog(@"i is %d", i);
#endif
```

However, better (when the formatting statement is non-trivial):

```
NSInteger i = 1;
NSLog(@"i is %ld", (long)i);
```

Answer (score 2):

64bit warning.

```
NSInteger i=[self.indexPathArray indexOfObject:[self indexPathForActiveText]];
```

You probably updated your xcode. The latest turned on a lot of warnings for when you're compiling against say an iphone 5s or ipad air (x86_64)

Comment: That should work, but why did it happen all the sudden? yesterday was no problem at all

Comment: You probably updated your xcode version. It turned on a lot of warnings for when you're compiling against say an iphone 5s or ipad air

Comment: @Nico No, these warnings have always been there.  More likely the OP decided to compile for arm64 (perhaps by running their code on a device rather than the Simulator).

Comment: I turns out I selected the 64-bit simulator. yesterday was 32-bit. The good thing is that I now know that I have to take care of this later on.

Comment: When changing int for NSInteger I then get a warning on the line [self moveRows:i-1];